# Why is it needed to erase the first MByte of an OpenBSD CRYPTO device?

Tags: openbsd

from: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bioctl

```
The following command, executed from the command line, would configure
     the device softraid0 with one special device (/dev/sd2e) and an
     encrypting volume:

    # bioctl -c C -l /dev/sd2e softraid0

     bioctl will ask for a passphrase, which will be needed to unlock the
     encrypted disk.  After creating a newly encrypted disk, the first
     megabyte of it should be zeroed, so tools like fdisk(8) or disklabel(8)
     don't get confused by the random data that appears on the new disk.  This
     can be done with the following command (assuming the new disk is sd3):

    # dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/rsd3c bs=1m count=1
```

**My question**: but exactly why is it needed to erase the first MByte of the CRYPTO device? Are there any disadvantages if I miss doing this?

Comment: I am wondering not why, but how does this not break it. If you write over something, do you not break it?

Comment: @richard These are the initial steps for setting up the device. There is no real content yet, just random data.

Comment: OK, so latter it will get filled with stuff that confuses fdisk or disklabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from Nick Holland on OpenBSD misc mailing list:

```
So...today, you take a couple disks, zero the first 10MB, put a 1G boot
partition and make the rest RAID, then build a mirrored set, do your
testing, and call it done.

Tomorrow, you take the same disk, zero the first 10MB, put a 1GB boot
partition on it, and make the rest RAID, and intend to build a crypto
RAID partition on it.  Except...Poof! your RAID1 chunk is baaack!  Why?
 Because you didn't touch the softraid data which is 1GB up the disk.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is described with the sentences:

```
so tools like fdisk(8) or disklabel(8) don't get confused by the 
random data that appears on the new disk
```

After creating the crypto device the data there will be random, (even if there would be originally all zeros on the disk, because of the decription). `fdisk` and `disklabel` could get confused if that data looks like (almost) valide partition table information.

So you have to zero **through the encryption** to write non-random data there before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

You already quoted the answer.

> so tools like fdisk(8) or disklabel(8) don't get confused by the random data that appears on the new disk

Tools used to partition the disk (like `fdisk` and `parted`) or tools used to label the disk (like `disklabel`) will try to read the existing MBR. If the MBR is zero then they will treat it as being empty. If it is non-zero, they will try to understand it's content. But the content will be completely random in your case. It will confuse those tools and may crash them in the worst case if they are not prepared for reading bogus values.